# HyperledgerComposer: How i can create a BusinessNetwork Cards from a identity issued?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have read the documentation at "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue".
Then I want to issue identity with Javascript API. I have done it. But if I do it with command line "composer identity issue ...", then I have a card in the current directory that i will "Composer card import" later. So, How I create a card with identity issued via Javascript API

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the User name and the Enrollment secret, you can use the composer card create command e.g.

`composer card create --file my_new_user.card --businessNetworkName my-test-network --connectionProfileFile connection.json --user my_new_user --enrollSecret my_new_secret`

The connection.json can be the one that is used by the admin for the business network.

Then use the `composer card import -f my_new_user.card` command.

This document covers the composer card create command.